# How do I send request data from axios module in Node.js to my pug files in the view folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm trying to make a request to my github profile and sending that data object to one of my pug files in the views folder.

I was successfully able to `console.log` data in the `app.js` file, but don't know how to send that data to other parts of my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's part of my `app.js` file:

```
app.get('/articles/add', function(req, res){
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/roadtocode822')
    .then(function(response){
    res.render('add_article', {
        data: response.data
    });
});
```

Here's my view file `add_article.pug`:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 #{title}
    h4 #{data.login}
    form(method='POST', action='/articles/add')
        #form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        #form-group
            label Author:
            input.form-control(name='author', type='text')
        #form-group
            label Body:
            textarea.form-control(name='body')
        br
        input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit',value='Submit')
```

Comment: You have to save that data somewhere in memory or storage or database to use it in other parts

Comment: How do I bring the data out of the function scope?

Comment: It's not recommended way, but I'll tell you. Like `window` in browser, node.js use `global` as global object. So you can `global.data = YOUR_DATA` then, you can use `global.data` anywhere. But it's not recommended way, I recommend you to use database such as redis

Comment: Can you point me to any reading or tutorial that can show me how to Do it the right way

Comment: There's no such thing like **right way** in javascript. Why I said it's not recommended is because the data inside the memory(if you save it in `global` object) will disappear if the server's down.